# How do I run occasional tasks that update data in a database?

Tags: database, elixir, phoenix-framework

Ooccasionaly I need to run tasks that update data in a database. I might need to run them ever again, or not a new server - no idea. For I need to run them once and in a certain release only. And they should be outside of git index.

Some tutorial suggest that I run them with "custom migration", in which a 2nd directory for migrations is created called "custom_migrations" and they'll be run from there via `Ecto.Migrator`. But this will case a problem: I run all of the `custom_migrations`, then delete all of migration files (because I won't need them anywhere else, not on a new server either, once I've run them), then create new ones when a need arises, and then `Ecto.Migrator` will complain about absense of the migrations that I've deleted.

I'm also aware of `./bin/my_app eval MyApp.Tasks.custom_task1` but it's not convinient because I'll have to call it manually and passing arguments to a function isn't convinient via the command line.

What I want is: create a several files that I want to be run in this current release, once. Store them in a certain directory of an application. Deploy a application. They'll get run automatically, probably on application boot and then I remove them. Then, after some time, I may want to create new ones and only those new ones will need to get run.

How to do this? What's a recommended way in Ellixir/Phoenix?

Comment: Use scripts (`*.exs`) for whatever you want to run. Run a process that would read the content of this folder, execute scripts located there, and remove them.

Comment: I think you'll get better answers for this type of question over in https://elixirforum.com/ 
Custom data migrations might be overkill.  Perhaps the guidelines written for Phoenix would be relevant: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html#ecto-migrations-and-custom-commands

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin you mean, by creatiing a process or `Task` in `MyApp123.Application > start(_, _)`  ?  ... that would read a directory and execute  a script in it.

Comment: For instance, yes. Or, better, in start_phase/3.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin say "execute scripts them and then delete them". What's the point of deleting them in a release, if a release has already been compiled, and it run on a server anyway? Or do you mean "deploy, let them get run on a server in a release. And then delete them **locally** so that they won't be included into the next releases"?

Comment: Yeah, locally, you mentioned you do not want them to be kept between releases.

Comment: Ok what type of data would you need to constantly update a database with?  In these files are you manually entering the data or are you pulling data from a different source thats getting updated?  Manually updating data...you could create a form that would submit data into the database...pulling from a source you can write some sort of .exs file that on run imports data from your other source.